# Record exact value that caused change in comparison of Row values python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to spot the differences between two columns in a pandas' `DataFrame`

Say I have two columns which I have compared to spot changes. Then I find a row like this in output *MOO89-'WR' --> M0089-'Wx'*. This means that the row value was modified from first to second. What should I do to record the output  of the change and record  in another column ? I want 'x' stored in another columns, since it is the one that caused a change.

```
Final_df["Unique"] = Final_df['New_Branching Logic'][~Final_df['New_Branching Logic'].isin(Final_df['Branching Logic)'])].drop_duplicates()
Final_df
```

I have tried this code but its not capture the real value that caused the change. I want to create a column with the value that caused change as in this case its *x* is what caused change. HERE IS THE LINK TO TESTDATA SAMPLE [TESTData.csv](https://github.com/livingstone90/Compare-CSV/blob/master/TESTDATA.csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns all of the charcaters that are different in the second string (column 'New_Branching Logic'):

```
def string_comparison(row):
    return [row['New_Branching Logic'][i] 
            for i in range(len(row['Branching Logic'])) 
            if row['Branching Logic'][i] != row['New_Branching Logic'][i]]
```

Then, you can apply it on every row of the `DataFrame`:

```
Final_df["Unique"] = Final_df.apply(string_comparison, axis=1)
```

When testing on the following DataFrame:

```
Final_df = pd.DataFrame([["M0089-'WR'","M0089-'Wx'"]], 
    columns=['Branching Logic', 'New_Branching Logic'])
```

I get this result:

```
    Branching Logic     New_Branching Logic     Unique
0   M0089-'WR'          M0089-'Wx'              [x]
```

In the 'Unique' column is a list of all the different characters.

Comment: In the function, Is it possible to have more columns there, say like 10 columns

Comment: Yes, but it will only return the differences between the columns named 'New_Branching Logic' and 'Branching Logic'. The elements belonging to other columns won't be used in the function.

Comment: I am getting this error *("'float' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0')* So I have edited the question and added some test data that I am using one column is old another one is new. so you can test with that data we see why the error.

Comment: Hey, are you still available you assist me.that error is still happening

Comment: Maybe you have NaNs in your DataFrame. You could use `Final_df.fillna({'Branching Logic':" ", 'New_Branching Logic':" "}, inplace=True)` to fill the NaNs in the columns

Comment: Done the same and the error changes to "IndexError: ('string index out of range', 'occurred at index 0')"

Comment: your assistance will really be appreciated